# Highcharts Polar Plot area scaling issues

Tags: highcharts

I created a graph with Highcharts polar type. The boundaries of chart are overflowing. Can anyone please help me in fixing the graph.

Please find my problem on JSFiddle: 
    [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jawq31bh/1/)
Code:

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            showAxes: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360
        },

        xAxis: {

            tickInterval: 45,
            min: 0,
            max: 360,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '°';
                }
            },
            lineWidth: 10,
            lineColor: "#000000",
            gridLineWidth: 5,
            gridLineColor: "#000000"
        },

        yAxis: {

            offset: 120,            
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',  
            min: 0,
            max: 4,
            visible: false,
            endOnTick: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: 0,
                pointInterval: 45
            },
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0
            },
            line: {
                color: "#ff0000",
              lineWidth: 10
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Line2',
            data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
            pointPlacement: 'between'
        }]
    });
});
```

This produces axis outside plot area. I would like to increase plot area so as to see the meeting point of extremist end points.

Comment: I reported this issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5073 - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the Plot is overflowing is because you have set a Maximum Value for the yAxis of 4 but in your data you have values that are greater than 4, like 8,7,6 and 5.

Just remove the `max: 4` option from the yAxis Object and your Chart will display fine.